# MySQL/MariaDB groups of 7 days interval

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Database version: MySQL 8+ and 10.5.8-MariaDB.

Some data examples which can be found on [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1RZfkoNa) as well .

```
CREATE TABLE `vicidial_closer_log` (
  `closecallid` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `call_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(18) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `uniqueid` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`closecallid`),
  KEY `call_date` (`call_date`),
  KEY `uniqueid` (`uniqueid`),
  KEY `phone_number` (`phone_number`),
  KEY `dt_phone` (`call_date`,`phone_number`),
  KEY `dt_phone_uniqueid` (`call_date`,`phone_number`,`uniqueid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ;

insert into `vicidial_closer_log`(call_date,phone_number,uniqueid) values
('2023-01-17 16:01:25','1000106338','1673708481.829754'),
('2023-01-17 16:02:04','1000106338','1673708519.829761'),
('2023-01-19 18:20:23','1000106338','1673889620.853236'),
('2023-01-19 18:27:04','1000106338','1673890021.853302'),
('2023-01-22 15:30:09','1000106338','1674138607.888573'),
('2023-01-22 15:53:06','1000106338','1674139983.888844'),
('2023-01-22 15:53:32','1000106338','1674140009.888856'),
('2023-01-22 15:54:15','1000106338','1674140052.888863'),
('2023-01-22 15:54:51','1000106338','1674140088.888874'),
('2023-01-22 15:55:56','1000106338','1674140153.888888'),
('2023-01-22 15:56:36','1000106338','1674140193.888895'),
('2023-01-27 11:06:40','1000106338','1674554798.944512');
```

What have I tried ?

I can fix this by creating another table and save the result(unika,doppia) per each number using a trigger, but I can't find a solution using the query only.

My problem for the above given data example on the `2023-01-27 11:06:40` the query should return 0(unika). Something like below:

```
1000106338   2023-01-17 16:01:25 ----- > unika
1000106338   2023-01-17 16:02:04 ----- > doppia
1000106338   2023-01-19 18:20:23 ----- > doppia
1000106338   2023-01-19 18:27:04 ----- > doppia
1000106338   2023-01-22 15:30:09 ----- > doppia
1000106338   2023-01-22 15:53:06 ----- > doppia
1000106338   2023-01-22 15:53:32 ----- > doppia
1000106338   2023-01-22 15:54:15 ----- > doppia
1000106338   2023-01-22 15:54:51 ----- > doppia
1000106338   2023-01-22 15:55:56 ----- > doppia
1000106338   2023-01-22 15:56:36 ----- > doppia 
1000106338   2023-01-27 11:06:40 ----- > unika
```

The first entry per the number should be unika , if the same number enters again for the next 7 days it should be doppia , at the 8th day , unika again

Comment: Why last row is marked as 'unica'? I see 5-day difference only...

Comment: @Akina because every entry between the first value and 7 days should be doppia and then the counter resets .

Comment: If so then the result is iterative, and you need in recursive CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
enumerated AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY call_date) rn
  FROM vicidial_closer_log
),
marked AS (
  SELECT *, call_date AS last_date, CAST('unica' AS CHAR(6)) AS mark
  FROM enumerated 
  WHERE rn = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT enumerated.*,
         CASE WHEN marked.last_date > enumerated.call_date - INTERVAL 7 DAY
              THEN marked.last_date
              ELSE enumerated.call_date
              END,
         CASE WHEN marked.last_date > enumerated.call_date - INTERVAL 7 DAY
              THEN 'doppia'
              ELSE 'unica'
              END  
  FROM enumerated
  JOIN marked ON enumerated.rn = marked.rn + 1
)
SELECT closecallid, call_date, phone_number, uniqueid, mark
FROM marked 
ORDER BY call_date;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zSo2j2rQ)

Comment: It gives the expected result, thank you.  I need some time to study recursive cte as I haven't use recursive cte .

Comment: @ErgestBasha Use `SELECT *` in last query - this will allow you to investigate the recursion flow. PS. If you need to do this for different phone numbers then you'd add PARTITION BY to ROW_NUMBER and according condition to recursive part joining condition - for each number you'd enumerate and process rows separately.

Comment: this is a filter which takes only one phone_number and based on the result (unika/doppia) it changes the flow of the call.